# Find $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos x-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the limit (if it exists)

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\cos x-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}$$

I used the sandwich rule in this way:

$$0\leq\left|\frac{\cos x-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}\right|\leq\left|\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}\right|\leq\left|x^2\right|\underset{x→0}{→}0$$

Which would mean that the limit is $0$. Nevertheless, Wolfram (as well as the solution we were given) says that the limit is undefined. Is there a mistake in what I did?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't trust wolfram alpha for this.

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to be $\color{red}{-}\tfrac{x^2}{2}$ and not $\color{blue}{+}\tfrac{x^2}{2}$ in the numerator?

Comment: Yes, it is $\color{red}{-\tfrac{x^2}{2}}$. I guess you are suggesting that if it was a + my answer would be correct, so is there a mistake?

Comment: Consider, for example, the restriction to $y=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the path $x = 0$, we find

$$\lim_{y\to0} 0 = 0$$

Along the path $y = 0$, we find

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x - 1 - x^2/2}{x^4}$$

$$=^{H}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\sin x - x}{4x^3}$$

$$=^{H}\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\cos x - 1}{12x^2}$$

$$=- \infty \neq 0$$

Therefore, the limit does not exist.

Your mistakes:

Neither

$$\left|\frac{cosx-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}\right|\leq\left|\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}\right|$$

(as mentioned by StackTD)

nor

$$\left|\frac{\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}\right|\leq\left|x^2\right|$$

is true.

So we learnt one has to be very careful manipulating inequalities. Even I was confused!

You also asked why  $|\cos x−1−x^2/2|≤|x2/2|$ is not true.

By triangle inequality,

$|\cos x−1−x^2/2| \leq |\cos x−1| +|−x^2/2| = |\cos x−1| + |x^2/2| \leq 2 + 1/2 x^2$
while it is not true that $|\cos x−1| + |x^2/2| \leq 1/2 x^2$. Take for example $x = 1$

Comment: I see, because it may be that $x^4+y^4<1$?

Comment: Take for example x = 0,0001, y = 0,0001

Answer (score 2):

The limit doesn't exist.

Note that:
$$\lim_{y \to 0} \left( \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos x-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}\right)=\lim_{y \to 0} \left(\frac{0}{0+y^4}\right) = 0$$
but:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\cos x-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x-1-\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4} = -\infty$$

---

I asked about the sign because the limit
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\cos x-1\color{red}{+}\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}$$
would have be more interesting, since then also:
$$\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\cos x-1\color{red}{+}\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4+y^4}\right)=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\cos x-1\color{red}{+}\frac{x^2}{2}}{x^4} = 0$$

Comment: Thanks, so that means that the sandwich rule isn't always proof that the limit exists, or that there's a mistake in the sandwich I did?

Comment: @JonathanMartinez $|\cos x-1-x^2/2| \le |x^2/2|$ is not true; $|\cos x-1+x^2/2| \le |x^2/2|$ is though.

Comment: Nah, that's wrong, this can be proven using triangle inequality. I included what's wrong in my post. By triangle inequality $|\cos x - 1 - x^2/2| \leq |\cos x - 1| + |-x^2/2| $

Comment: @Math_QED What do you mean? Pick e.g. $x=1$, $|\cos 1-1-1^2/2| \not\le |1^2/2|$...

Comment: You are right! Sorry! It looks like we both found an error.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see why $|\cos x-1-x^2/2| \le |x^2/2|$ is not true... is it not true that $|-x|\leq|x|$?

Comment: Will edit my post.

Comment: Ok I think I got it... only if $x=2\pi k$ the equality holds, but it will never be smaller. thanks a lot :)